# In WPF how to add menu item event?

Tags: wpf, events, menu, click

In my WPF application, I add a menu then add several menu items under it. For example, one of my menu item is "Main Item", then I add subItem1, subItem2 and subItem3 under "Main Item". I want to click subItem1 and do something(e.g. MessageBox.show a message). Why I cannot find the event for this subItem1? How can I add the click event for subItem1? I find the property for subItem1 under the collection property for "Main Item", but can only see property, cannot see event list. How can I add click event for subItem1? Thank you!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In your xaml:

```
<Menu IsMainMenu="True">
<MenuItem Header="MainMenu">
<MenuItem Header="subItem1" 
 x:Name="subItem1" Click="subItem1_Click">
</MenuItem>
</MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

In your code-behind:

```
private void subItem1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Ohhh.. So in WPF you must manually type the events for certain Controls? Instead of just double-clicking something in the Event list. Sweet! Thanks! +1, you just answered a question I just finished typing. :)

Comment: @βӔḺṪẶⱫŌŔ you can double click on the menu item to get the auto-generated code.  To do this, first put the cursor on the `MenuItem` line in your XAML that contains the menu you want to add a handler to.  That should expose the menu item in the graphical designer.  Then double-click that menu in the graphical designer to generate the code-behind shell.