# Enabling/disabling menu items - Expression Blend

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expression-blend

I need to disable a particular menuitem when it is clicked. How can I write the code for this within the event handler?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codebehind event handler:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ((MenuItem)sender).IsEnabled = false;
}
```

"sender" is the item clicked, we need to cast it to MenuItem to be able to set its IsEnabled property.

Here's how to wire up the event handler in your xaml:
[In WPF how to add menu item event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479151/in-wpf-how-to-add-menu-item-event)

Comment: Avoid code only answers. Add some description about your answer, may be some useful links

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Hiya there, while this may well answer the question, please be aware that other users might not be as knowledgeable as you. Why don't you add a little explanation as to why this code works? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Understood, edited with a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from the code behind or use an event trigger (which is usually my preferred option for very simple tasks, as you can define them as a resource and reuse).

**Code Behind Answer:**

```
<MenuItem Header="Click Me" Click="MenuItem_Click">
```

---

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
   if (menuItem != null) menuItem.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

**XAML Only Answer:**

```
<MenuItem Header="Click Me">
    <MenuItem.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MenuItem.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(MenuItem.IsEnabled)">
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False" />
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </MenuItem.Triggers>
</MenuItem>
```